# Meaning of "Please submit a solution that captures the business domain for the problem"

Tags: interviewing

Recently I was invited to complete a technical programming test as part of a job interview.  I had the weekend to complete the assignment, and to publish it on GitHub for the company to review.

The test in short asked me to convert integer values to English within a certain range (e.g. 47 becomes forty seven).  One of the additional guidelines for the test was "Please submit a solution that captures the business domain for the problem".  I did not know what that meant, so I ignored it.

Despite providing a working solution I failed to be selected for the next round, and one of the reasons given was that I failed to provide "a solution that captures the business domain for the problem".  Sure, I should have asked the meaning of this requirement, and it is too late now.

Please can someone tell me what this requirement means?  Are they asking for Use Case / UML diagrams?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a coding/documentation terminology question, not workplace.

Comment: You might also post an appropriately modified version of your solution on code review stack exchange and ask specifically in the review how you can "better capture the business domain for this problem".

Answer (score 4):

Often very talented developers under-value domain knowledge and relevance. "Business domain" is the business context in which you are presenting a solution, and it is critical in providing a correct solution.

In your interview example, like in all software development, the business domain of the translation system is very important for understanding the implementation you select. To illustrate, if the business domain was for language tutorial translation, performance doesn't matter as much as correct grammar. Making a high volume, memory efficient solution is overkill and wastes resources (time and money). However, grammatically correct output (proper hyphenation, capitalization, etc.) would be very important.

However, if you were taking optical character recognition input from a bank check validation system that needs to process thousands of checks per minute, and validate the translation against the written amount from another input, then you need a very different solution. Focusing on rapid translation and creating a solid API to your component would be important. Grammatically correct results are meaningless - only pattern matching matters.

In your interview, ignoring the business domain (either provided or an explanation for an imaginary context that you saw as being applicable) does not give the reviewer the ability to judge the quality *and* appropriateness of your solution.

I hope the explanation helps explain how business domain should impact code review. Too much emphasis on coding and not enough on the business is unfortunately common with very talented developers. The best ones are the ones that combine business domain and coding knowledge.

EDIT:

You make a statement that you are abbreviating the interview question ("the test in short asked me..."). More context would reveal whether the interview included a business domain or the interviewee was supposed to describe one. Either way, they probably expected an explanation of what scope the solution was trying to address for the business domain in the short time given to solve the problem. This would demonstrate effective awareness of the business domain and use of limited resources (one weekend) to complete a task.

If no explanation was required, then "submit a solution that captures the business domain" means that your code should be obviously skewed toward addressing the core of the business domain implied or stated in the question. The result was that the provided solution failed to address the core of the problem or demonstrate business domain awareness, based on the reviewer's judgment.

Comment: This answers to the importance of considering the business domain, but from this I still have no idea about the OP's question "Give a solution which captures the business domain of the problem (to convert integers into an English-language spelled-out description of the number)."

Comment: I edited my response. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question: You **should have asked** what they meant by this weird sentence. A translation into English would have been great. I could imagine a company giving you intentionally vague requirements, just to check that you don't go ahead with vague requirements but first make sure that you know *exactly* what they want you to do.

Asking *us* what this company wanted is pointless. We have no idea. The company gave the requirements, they knew what they wanted (maybe), they are the ones to ask.